# Is there a way of localizing Teams?

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams, internationalization, localization

I'm prospecting Stack Overflow For Teams for my ... well, team, and I'm just ironing out the edges so I can present it to my boss.

The issue here is that, while there are some who are proficient in English, the majority speaks, and writes in Portuguese. Others have absolutely no knowledge at all of the former.

I searched everywhere, but could not find it (call me blind if it's in clear sight): Where can I change the overall interface language to Portuguese? 
If unavailable, is there a way of manually localizing it (via `.resx` files, for example)?

My team is in a Basic plan.

Comment: I don't think there is a localized version now. The localized SO instances are translated via Transifex.  It would be interesting to learn if Teams is at least at the dev / architecture level ready to be handled in the same way.

Comment: Good question, this can be a show stopper for companies with teams working under legislations that says that workers "have the right to work in the local language".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, but right now Teams is only in English. It's on our radar, and something we'd like to do, but at the moment it's not on our roadmap.

Comment: If you guys consider GitHub'bing the localization strings, I'd be happy to help translating.

Comment: As EricWu, I'd be happy to translate the localization strings (in French for my part). Is it planned on the roadmap now ? @Juice

Comment: It would be amazing if @Juice would help prioritize localization of Stackoverflow for Teams to other languages!

Comment: Hi Juice. Any news about localization roadmap?

Comment: It's not on the roadmap, but to your knowledge, is there any browser plugin that does on-the-fly automatic translation known to "not crash Teams too much"? (i.e. that would still allow to use most of the basic functionalities)