# Can I use another language than English on Stack Overflow for Teams questions/answers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, english

In the past few days I signed for SO Teams. Being a user of the public SO site, I know the rule of using English in both questions and answers.

But the Teams version is like a private area, just for me and my team, so I'd like to know if we can use Spanish for the questions/answers, since that is our home language.

This question is more about the incidence in the search/indexing of words, phrases, etc, and the returned 'relevant results'. It's neither about following a norm that does not apply in the private context, nor changing the site's UI to Spanish.

Can the site search results be affected if the language of the questions/answers were not English?

Comment: It might. SO's internal search has always been trash, though. It's not directly tied to languages, but usually characters. There's a lot of non-english sites in the network, and all the sites run on the same engine, so you could always test searching spanish Stack Overflow for a more accurate pointer.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is there a way of localizing Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390961/11682469)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do whatever you want in your private Team. You're on your own when it comes to quality control, editing, curating.

You can post as many link only / code only or even fun posts as you like.

I doubt the search / indexing is or will be geared to Spanish or any other language except English. So search will be as good (or bad, depending on who you ask) as it is on the
public Q/A sites. It might give slightly different results in case they are using SQL Server Full Text search instead of Elastic but that is an implementation detail [Taryn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/taryn), the bluefeeted dba, needs to confirm.