# Add localization/foreign language interface to Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, localization

I am interested in using Stack Overflow for teams as part of our knowledge management. It would love to have the interface in a language different from English, which would facilitate the implementation in our organization.

In 2019, someone asked the following:

[Is there a way of localizing Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390961/is-there-a-way-of-localizing-teams)

It was said that localization (foreign language interface) was on the table. Is there a roadmap for the localization feature in terms of available languages?

Comment: It's better if you ping the staff there - at least if they see enough people requesting this, they might reconsider adding localization sooner - I voted to close a duplicate to prevent information entropy - but please do ping Juice that the feature is highly sought for

Comment: What do you mean by pinging? Do you mean sending him a message? not sure how to do this.

Comment: eh, like leaving a comment on the linked post :) By pinging I mean "@-mentioning", the thing you can do when replying in comments (although this will not be necessary since Juice is the post author) to get the person notified. And upvote the request. Other than that, there is little we can do - you can try using "contact us" but it is unlikely they will respond as Meta is also the official support channel for Teams

Comment: Yes, it would be amazing if @Juice would help prioritize localization of Stackoverflow for Teams to other languages!

Comment: Not here - there :) The mentions don't work cross-post