# Non-Latin tags in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams, localization

Stack Overflow for Teams doesn't support non-Latin tags. Could this please be implemented? Maybe as an option in site settings if this feature may harm other Stack Overflow for Teams users.

Localized Stack Overflow sites like Stack Overflow in Russian allow non-Latin tags.

Comment: Welcome to the venerable tradition of asking SE to implement translations of Teams! :) Unfortunately the answer is probably - in 6 to 8. I'll suggest a closure towards the official response (basically "nope") in a sec - feel free to ping Juice there to let them know the feature is still highly sought for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of localizing Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390961/is-there-a-way-of-localizing-teams)

Comment: @OlegValter I'm not asking about translation the UI (this is a huge work), but allowing to use non-Latin tags looks pretty simple (of course if there is no ASCII-only based back-end for that).

Comment: well, I assume that asking for a part of the work to be done is going to result in the same response, but we can try, I guess - I can retract the VTC if you want. It won't hurt to ping either way because your request may have better chances of being addressed if they decide to localize the full thing.